# How to detect if contacts had been accessed in android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I want to create a service that could detect if contacts or sms contents is being access by any application. I know that these are accessed using contentResolver and contentObserver only provides notification when the data is changed or updated. How this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect if your *own* data is being accessed by another app, but you have no way to know if two completely independent apps are communicating in this fashion.

So, you are welcome to create your own ROM mod that ships your own version of the contacts and SMS providers, that collects the data you seek. However, you have no means of doing this from an ordinary SDK app.